# TinyMCE in modal, modal won't reopen after passing data to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm currently running an HTML template that has a placeholder div, and when the user clicks inside the `div`, a modal pops up with an instance of TinyMCE. So far so good.

TinyMCE works here as far as adding text/content, and then you hit a button that closes the modal and passes the content into the placeholder `div` in the same format. (Think of it like the user viewing a template for a static page, they want to insert content so the modal allows them to use TinyMCE to do so and then they hit the button to view it in the 'live' template).

Anyway, this works fine. The problem is, if you notice an error or typo and need to call TinyMCE again, It won't work. Once the content passes to the `div`, it no longer triggers the modal when clicking in the `div`. I'm not a JavaScript expert by any means so I'm sure something is wrong on that side.

Here's the code. Everything works as expected, but I just need to be able to keep the action of clicking the `div` and loading the modal to edit the content from TinyMCE:

```
<div class="row middle">
  <div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth">
    <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
      <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="fullModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fullLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="fullModal">Content Library:</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h3>Create your own content</h3>
              <form id="form-data3" method="post">
                <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea3" name="fullText"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Content">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var $modalFull = $('#fullModal').modal({
    show: false
  });

  $('.fullWidth').on('click', function() {
    $modalFull.modal('show');
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form-data3").submit(function(e) {
      var content3 = tinymce.get("mytextarea3").getContent();

      $(".fullContent").html(content3);
      jQuery.noConflict();
      $('#fullModal').modal('hide');
      $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$(".fullContent").html(content3);`, you are overwriting the modal's markup.

Place it outside that `div`.

```
<div class="row middle">
  <div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth">
    <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="fullModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fullLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="fullModal">Content Library:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <h3>Create your own content</h3>
        <form  id="form-data3" method="post">
          <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea3" name="fullText"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Save Content">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense! Thank you! Trying this now